# Issue with inserting multiple RSS items to DB

Tags: php, mysql, json, xml, rss

**Situation:**

I have a PHP script that attempts to merge 26 different RSS feeds and insert up to 1000 items from those feeds into a MySQL DB.

Hosting: Bluehost

MySQL Version: 5.7.23-23

PHP version via phpversion(): 8.0.17

PHP version via My Admin info:

- PHP: 7.4.30
- Database client version: libmysql
- mysqlnd 7.4.30
- PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation

**Issue:**

The script only inserts 26 RSS feed items, 1 item from each RSS feed into the DB, i.e. it does not insert ALL RSS items from the 26 feeds (up to 1000). I've used this same script to build an RSS feed and JSON file that includes all items from the 26 RSS items.

**Question:**

Can anyone help identify why this script isn't inserting all RSS items from all the RSS feeds as expected? Thank you for the help.

**PHP Script Code:**

```
<?php
$json = new DOMDocument();

$data = array();

$resources = array(
    array( 'type' => 'Article', 'source' => 'Source 1', 'feedurl' => 'http://www.example1.com/feed/', 'id' => '1' ),
    array( 'type' => 'Article', 'source' => 'Source 2', 'feedurl' => 'https://example2.com/feed', 'id' => '2' ),
    array( 'type' => 'Article', 'source' => 'Source 3', 'feedurl' => 'https://example3.com/feed', 'id' => '3' )
);

foreach ( $resources as $resource ) {
  $json->load( $resource['feedurl'] );

  foreach ( $json->getElementsByTagName( 'item' ) as $node ) {
  $item = array(
    'source'  => $resource['source'],
    'type'  => $resource['type'],
    'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName( 'title' )->item( 0 )->nodeValue,
    'link'  => $node->getElementsByTagName( 'link' )->item( 0 )->nodeValue,
    'date'  => $node->getElementsByTagName( 'pubDate' )->item( 0 )->nodeValue,
    'id'  => $resource['id']
  );

  array_push( $data, $item );
  }
}

usort( $data, function( $a, $b ) {
  return strtotime( $b['date'] ) - strtotime( $a['date'] );
});

$servername = '???';
$username = '???';
$password = '???';
$dbname = '???';

// Create connection
$DBconnection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//sql query
$sql = "INSERT INTO articles(source, type, title, url, date, id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

//insert into mysql table
$stmt = $DBconnection->prepare($sql);

$limit = 1000;

for ( $x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++ ) {
    $source = $data[ $x ]['source'];
    $type = $data[ $x ]['type'];
    $title = htmlspecialchars(str_replace( ' & ', ' & ', $data[ $x ]['title'] ));
    $link = htmlspecialchars($data[ $x ]['link']);
    $date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $data[ $x ]['date'] ) );
    $id = $data[ $x ]['id'];

    $stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $source, $type, $title, $link, $date, $id);

    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
$DBconnection->close();

?>
```

Comment: Try putting `$stmt =` inside the for loop

Comment: @JacobMulquin thanks. I tried adding '$stmt =' inside the for loop, but unfortunately it still only inserts the same number of items. it doesn't insert all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the code and tested locally, it appears to be working:

```
$resources = [
  ['type' => 'Article', 'source' => 'Hackaday', 'feedurl' => 'https://hackaday.com/blog/feed/', 'id' => '1'],
  ['type' => 'Article', 'source' => 'The Daily WTF', 'feedurl' => 'http://syndication.thedailywtf.com/TheDailyWtf', 'id' => '2']
];

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$articles = [];

foreach ($resources as $resource) {
  $dom->load($resource['feedurl']);

  foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $articles[] = [
      'id' => $resource['id'],
      'source' => $resource['source'],
      'type' => $resource['type'],
      'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    ];
  }
}

usort($articles, function ($a, $b) {
  return strtotime($b['date']) - strtotime($a['date']);
});

$server = '???';
$user = '???';
$pass = '???';
$db = 'so';

$mysql = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);
$mysql->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles (source TEXT, type TEXT, title TEXT, url TEXT, date DATETIME, id INT);');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO articles (source, type, title, url, date, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

$stmt = $mysql->prepare($sql);

foreach ($articles as $article) {
  $source = $article['source'];
  $type = $article['type'];
  $title = htmlspecialchars($article['title']);
  $link = htmlspecialchars($article['link']);
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($article['date']));
  $id = $article['id'];

  $stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $source, $type, $title, $link, $date, $id);
  $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
$mysql->close();
```

That adds all the records:

```
MariaDB [so]> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|       22 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this Jacob, much appreciated. It's the weirdest thing, I'm still not seeing all RSS items in the DB. I see 1 RSS item per RSS feed - so 2 in total. I host my site with Bluehost - is it possible that there may be some server, PHP, and/or MySQL settings causing this?

Comment: Hmm this is very interesting indeed! Are you using the code I posted exactly as-is? I wonder if it has anything to do with the feeds themself, if you do a `count($articles)` after they are all fetched and added, what's the result? Also what version of PHP/MySQL are you using? There's a possibility there may be a bug somewhere. I'm using PHP 8.1.7 on Debian, with MySQL 10.5.15-MariaDB

Comment: I'm using the same script to merge all RSS feeds items into a JSON file and RSS feed, which is why I'm so perplexed why it doesn't work to insert into the DB.

I've used the script as is, with two exceptions:

1. Removed "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"
2. Added DB info.

I did an echo 'count($articles)'; after the last foreach loop and got: 22.

**Info:**

**MySQL:** 5.7.23-23

**PHP** via phpversion(): 8.0.17

**PHP** via My Admin info:
- PHP: 7.4.30
- Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.30
- PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation